# (SQL) Multiple joins on same table - more optimized way?

Tags: sql, join

I have the following code which produces my desired result:

```
SELECT  p.name,
        p.hobby1_id, h.code, h.description,
        p.hobby2_id, h2.code, h2.description
        p.hobby3_id, h3.code, h3.description
FROM    person p
        LEFT JOIN hobby h ON h.id = p.hobby1_id
        LEFT JOIN hobby h2 ON h2.id = p.hobby2_id
        LEFT JOIN hobby h3 ON h3.id = p.hobby3_id
```

Is there a more optimized way of this?  Like if possible, getting rid of `h2` and `h3`.  Thanks

Comment: Show us some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: Show please what is the meaning of the query. Just a small, general hint. Normally left joins are less efficient than 'classic' inner joins. So you can substitute them (or one of them) in the case you're sure that hobby2 or hobby3 are always not null

Comment: Is there a way of formatting text here like a table that I don't know of?  I'm having trouble with the tabs and spaces O_O thanks

Comment: @AwonDanag Tables in SO-posts are a little tricks. [There is a thread about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/311071) The essence: Create an `ASCII`-table and format it as code (4 step indentation or mark all lines and push `<ctrl>+k`). There are several online tools around to create such a table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the design. As it looks, your table `person` has got three columns with FKs to table `hobby` (hobby1_id to hobby3_id).

With this (bad) design there is no better way...

But there is a better structure:

```
table person
 - personID
 - name
 - more columns to store further details for one specific person

table hobby
 - hobbyID
 - hobby
 - more columns to store further details for this specific hobby

table person_hobby
- personID
- hobbyID
- Rank (if needed)
- more columns to specify details of this special mapping
```

This is a classical `n:m relation`

The table `person_hobby` defines a mapping between persons and hobbies. If needed you might add a column `Rank` to set "first" hobby over "second" and "third". You might implement rules to restrict this to three, but why should one do so...

Comment: So is it more recommended that I isolate the hobbies?  Because the three `id` columns for hobbies in the `person` table are required.

Comment: What does  *the three id columns for hobbies in the person table are required* mean? This is awfully bad design... If needed as a *table* you could introduce a `VIEW` and include the first three hobbies via `PIVOT`...

Comment: I'm actually preparing this query for a `VIEW`... anyway the `person` table has columns `hobby1_id`, `hobby2_id`, and so on.  I thought adding these three to the table would be trivial, than adding another table `person_hobby` as you suggested, which would mean longer queries...

Comment: @AwonDanag There is **nothing wrong with longer queries**, especially if they are shorter than yours :-) Just imagine your approach with `hobby4_id` up to `hobbyX_id`... Which one will be longer in the end? No, believe me: If this is something you can change this is worth the effort!

Comment: Well with **only** three `hobbies` I'm doubtful, but now I just received information from superiors that `hobbies` are going to be dynamic, so I'm following your suggestion of a separate table. :)

Comment: @AwonDanag, great! Take this as granted: Whenever you think, that you will need *not more than three*, you **will need more than three** later :-)